# Probability of at least $k$ successes in $t$ units of time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Say that some machine makes a beeping noise at random times (I just care about the mathematics, so it doesn't really matter what you call it). The time between each beep is exponentially distributed with some mean $\lambda$ (assume independence). Then my question is

> What is the probability that the machine makes at least $k$ beeps in $t$ units of time?

Let $X(t)$ be the number of beeping noises in the period $[0,t]$, then I guess the answer should be

$$P(X(t)\geq k) = 1 - P(X(t)\leq k-1),$$

however I'm not sure how I calculate the last term. If it were only $1$ beep, I guess it would be

$$P(X(t) = 1) = \int_0^t\frac1\lambda e^{-\tau/\lambda}\,\mathrm{d}\tau, $$
so I guess my main problem is how one extends to multiple occurences.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know the beeps of machine form a Poisson process? (of course, you need to assume the times between beeps are also independent.)

Comment: @Solitary Thank you for your help, yes I assume independence. I'm just looking at the Wikipedia for Poisson processes, I see that it should be a homogeneous Poisson Process. And then
$$P(X(t) = k) = \frac{(t\lambda^{-1})^k}{k!}e^{-t/\lambda} $$
and then I just need the probability of all the $0, 1, 2, ... k$. Does that make sense? (btw, I say $\lambda^{-1}$ because $\lambda$ is the mean time, not the rate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a Poisson process with rate $\mu=\lambda^{-1}$, or at the very least a gamma distribution with rate $\mu$. Assuming independent waiting times, then you're asking for the number of points from $0$ to $t$ $N_t \geq k$. Using complements, then you're asking for 0 arrivals until time $t$, or 1 arrival, or 2... So, since $N_t$ follows a $\text{Pois}(\mu t)$, then
$$P(N_t \geq k)  = 1-[P(N_t =0)+P(N_t =1)+ \dotsb +P(N_t = k-1)]=1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{e^{-\mu t}(\mu t)^i}{i!}. $$

Comment: Thank you, I just arrived to something similar in the comments above. Since I consider mean time between occurences as $\lambda$, and not the rate per time unit, should it not be $\lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: Sure, I changed my answer a little so that you can $\mu = \lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: +1. Thank you, I didn't ask to be nitpicky, I'm just still learning so I'm just making sure.

Comment: No problem, consistency is best!

Comment: Do you know how one could extend this, if instead that the time between occurrences was exponentially distributed, the time between occurrences was distributed with some density function $f(t)$?

Comment: If you call the intensity $\lambda(t)$ that varies with time, then the increment $N_t-N_s$ over the interval $(s,t]$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\int_s^t\lambda(u)\,du$.